# How to create a 3D plot with orthographic projections – Matlab

Tags: charts, matlab, 3d

How can I generate a 3D plot with the orthographic projections of a parametric curve on the inside walls of the 3D plot, as shown in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Cb9MsrnzrU) youtube video?

I can generate a 3D plot of the curve using the `plot3` function, but I cannot figure out how to create the blue orthographic projections on the inner walls of the cube or the red dashed lines:

[image]

Additionally, how could I generate and synchronize the 3 separate "Coordinate Functions" plots (not show on the diagram above but shown in the video)?